# PhantomJS and logging to the syslog

Tags: ubuntu, phantomjs, syslog

I would like to send messages through to the syslog daemon.

Similar to how

`user@ubuntu:~/phantomjs$ logger "hello world"`

would show

`Apr 18 03:53:45 ubuntu user: hello world`

I've been googling [syslog in phantomjs](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=syslog%20in%20phantomjs&oq=syslog%20in%20phantomjs&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2464j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) and all of the results I checked are irrelevant. Creating this question, I hope to make a relevant result :)

I am using ubuntu and phantomjs 1.9.7.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to [spawn a logger](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/child_process-examples.js).

Example:

```
require("child_process").spawn("logger 'jase is a pollywaffle'");
```